# How to capitalize first letter of each sentence?

Tags: c#, string

I know how to capitalize first letter in each word. But I want to know how to capitalize first letter of each sentence in C#.

Comment: You should know how your sentences end. The question is incomplete!

Answer (score 12):

This is not necessarily a trivial problem. Sentences can end with a number of different punctuation marks, and those same punctuation marks don't always denote the end of a sentence (abbreviations like Dr. may pose a particular problem because there are potentially many of them).

That being said, you might be able to get a "good enough" solution by using regular expressions to look for words after a sentence-ending punctuation, but you would have to add quite a few special cases. It might be easier to process the string character by character or word by word. You would still have to handle all the same special cases, but it might be easier than trying to build that into a regex.

There are lots of weird rules for grammar and punctuation. Any solution you come up with probably won't be able to take them all into account. Some things to consider:

- Sentences can end with different punctuation marks (. ! ?)
- Some punctuation marks that end sentences might also be used in the middle of a sentence (e.g. abbreviations such as Dr. Mr. e.g.)
- Sentences could contain nested sentences. Quotations could pose a particular problem (e.g. He said, "This is a hard problem! I wonder," he mused, "if it can be solved.")

Comment: How'd you get so many upvotes without actually providing an answer for the question? I want to know the name of your cologne!

Comment: @jdk: Fair point, but the spirit of my answer was more that you probably can't do a really good job of this in all cases. I added a little more advice for creating a "good enough" solution that might work *most* of the time.

Comment: When in grad school you need to either find a good solution or prove that it is NP-complete.

This answer is like proving it is NP-complete (aka just give up).

Comment: @earlNameless: Even for NP-complete problems, there are sometimes heuristics that can give good approximations (e.g. traveling salesman: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem). You can't find a really good solution, but you might be able to find a "good enough" approximation.

Answer (score 4):

As a first approximation, you could probably treat any sequence like `[a-z]\.[ \n\t]` as the end of a sentence.

Comment: @Joel Perhaps capturing the text before the punctuation too? It could help filtering out common abbreviations like Dr., Ms., Mrs., etc.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a sentence as a word containing spaces an ending with a period.

Comment: Or an exclamation mark. Or a question mark.
Also note that there might be empty sentences - for example, when there are three exclamation marks in a row.

Comment: sentences can end with other punctuation marks, and things like quotes can cause those punctuation markers to show otherplaces than at the end of a sentence.

Comment: @Fyodor Soikin - all punctuation can be checked by char.IsPunctuation and char.ToUpper for punctuation will return same char. so your worries are unnecessary.

Comment: Also, what happens if I'm a talking about C# 3.5, for example?

Comment: @Andrey char.IsPunctuation will return true,Which would, capitalise the which in this sentance incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

There's some VB code on [this page](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=536912) which shouldn't be too hard to convert to C#.

However, subsequent posts point out the errors in the algorithm.

[This blog](http://www.mardymonkey.co.uk/blog/index.php/2010/01/auto-capitalise-a-text-control-in-wpf) has some C# code which claims to work:

> It auto capitalises the first letter after every full stop (period), question mark and exclamation mark.
>
> UPDATE 16 Feb 2010: I’ve reworked it so that it doesn’t affect strings such as URL’s and the like

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget sentences with parentheses. Also, * if used as an idicator for bold text.

http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/parens.asp

Answer (score 0):

**I needed to do something similar, and this served my purposes.  I pass in my "sentences" as a `IEnumerable` of strings.**

```
// Read sentences from text file (each sentence on a separate line)
IEnumerable<string> lines = File.ReadLines(inputPath);

// Call method below
lines = CapitalizeFirstLetterOfEachWord(lines);

private static IEnumerable<string> CapitalizeFirstLetterOfString(IEnumerable<string> inputLines)
{
  // Will output: Lorem lipsum et

  List<string> outputLines = new List<string>();

  TextInfo textInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).TextInfo;

  foreach (string line in inputLines)
  {
    string lineLowerCase = textInfo.ToLower(line);
    string[] lineSplit = lineLowerCase.Split(' ');
    bool first = true;

   for (int i = 0; i < lineSplit.Length; i++ )
    {
      if (first)
      {
        lineSplit[0] = textInfo.ToTitleCase(lineSplit[0]);
        first = false;
      }
    }

    outputLines.Add(string.Join(" ", lineSplit));
  }

  return outputLines;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm little late, but just like You, I needed to capitalize every first character on each of my sentences.
I just fell here (and a lot of other pages while I was researching) and found nothing to help me out. So, I burned some neurons, and made a algorithm by myself.

**Here is my extension method to capitalize sentences:**

```
public static string CapitalizeSentences(this string Input)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Input))
            return Input;

        if (Input.Length == 1)
            return Input.ToUpper();


        Input = Regex.Replace(Input, @"\s+", " ");

        Input = Input.Trim().ToLower();
        Input = Char.ToUpper(Input[0]) + Input.Substring(1);


        var objDelimiters = new string[] { ". ", "! ", "? " };
        foreach (var objDelimiter in objDelimiters)
        {
            var varDelimiterLength = objDelimiter.Length;

            var varIndexStart = Input.IndexOf(objDelimiter, 0);
            while (varIndexStart > -1)
            {
                Input = Input.Substring(0, varIndexStart + varDelimiterLength) + (Input[varIndexStart + varDelimiterLength]).ToString().ToUpper() + Input.Substring((varIndexStart + varDelimiterLength) + 1);

                varIndexStart = Input.IndexOf(objDelimiter, varIndexStart + 1);
            }
        }


        return Input;
    }
```

**Details about the algorithm:**
This simple algorithm starts removing all double spaces. Then, it capitalize the first character of the string. then search for every delimiter. When find one, capitalize the very next character.

I made it easy to Add/Remove or Edit the delimiters, so You can change a lot how code works with a little change on it.
It doesn't check if the substrings go out of the string length, because the delimiters end with spaces, and the algorithm starts with a "Trim()", so every delimiter if found in the string will be followed by another character.

**Important:**
You didn't specify what were exactly your needs. I mean, it's a grammar corrector, it's just to prettify a text, etc... So, it's important to consider that my algorithm is just **perfect for my needs, that can be different of yours.**

*This algorithm was created to format a "Product Description" that isn't normalized (almost always it's entirely uppercased) in a nice format to the user (To be more specific, I need to show a pretty and "smaller" text for user. So, all characters in Upper Case is just opposite of what I want). So, it was not created to be grammatically perfect.

*Also, there maybe some exceptions where the character will not be uppercased because bad formatting.

*I choose to include spaces in the delimiter, so "http://www.stackoverflow.com" will not become "http://www.Stackoverflow.Com". In the other hand, sentences like "the box is blue.it's on the floor" will become "The box is blue.it's on the floor", and **not** "The box is blue.It's on the floor"

*In abbreviations cases, it will capitalize, but once again, it's not a problem because my needs is just show a product description (where grammar is not extremely critic). And in abbreviations like Mr. or Dr. the very first character is a name, so, it's perfect to be capitalized.

If You, or somebody else needs a more accurate algorithm, I'll be glad to improve it.

Hope I could help somebody!

Answer (score 0):

However you can make a class or method to convert each text in TitleCase. Here is the example you just need to call the method.

```
public static string ToTitleCase(string strX)
    {
        string[] aryWords = strX.Trim().Split(' ');

        List<string> lstLetters = new List<string>();
        List<string> lstWords = new List<string>();

        foreach (string strWord in aryWords)
        {
            int iLCount = 0;
            foreach (char chrLetter in strWord.Trim())
            {
                if (iLCount == 0)
                {
                    lstLetters.Add(chrLetter.ToString().ToUpper());
                }
                else
                {
                    lstLetters.Add(chrLetter.ToString().ToLower());
                }
                iLCount++;
            }
            lstWords.Add(string.Join("", lstLetters));
            lstLetters.Clear();
        }

        string strNewString = string.Join(" ", lstWords);

        return strNewString;
    }
```