# How can I capitalize each first letter of a word in a sentence?

Tags: c#, string, char

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to capitalize first letter of each sentence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784588/how-to-capitalize-first-letter-of-each-sentence)

```
public static string CapitalizeEachWord(this string sentence)
{
    string[] words = sentence.Split();
    foreach (string word in words)
    {
        word[0] = ((string)word[0]).ToUpper();                
    }
}
```

I'm trying to create a extension method for a helper class I'm trying to create for myself for future projects.

This one particular is supposed to capitalize each word appropriately. Meaning, the first letter of every word should be capitalized. I'm having trouble getting this to work.

It says I cannot convert a char to a string, but I remember being able to do that at some point. Maybe I'm forgetting a crucial part.

Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: @ChrisF: I don't think that's a duplicate of this question. In the other question it's asking about capitalizing the first word of each sentence. Here I want to capitalize the first letter of each word. Since I can .Split() the sentence, I have no need for Regex, but my attempts haven't worked - hence the question.

Comment: @Thomas - my mistake. Well how about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880597/how-can-i-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-each-word then? It's language agnostic, but there is a c# solution.

Comment: Other people have already answered your question, but here's some advice. First, you can't cast `char` to `string`, but `myChar.ToString()` will work. Second, strings are immutable. You can't re-assign an arbitrary character in a string (to do it this way, use `string.ToCharArray()`, work with the `char` array, and then call `new string()` on that array.

Comment: @Sapph: Why does (string) not work, but ToString() work? What does .ToString() do differently?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Maybe use the `ToTitleCase` method in the `TextInfo` class

[How to convert strings to lower, upper, or title (proper) case by using Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312890)

```
CultureInfo cultureInfo   = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
TextInfo textInfo = cultureInfo.TextInfo;

Console.WriteLine(textInfo.ToTitleCase(title));
```

Comment: Using this code we need to call the method every time. Is there any override method that we can force each text box to convert in title case on leave

Comment: Should be updated to use CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo instead of accessing the thread. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Also of note - if your string is all uppercase this won't convert the text (it looks like an acronym). Use `textInfo.ToTitleCase(title.ToLower())` to get title case on it.

Answer (score 9):

Here's how I do it:

```
public static string ProperCase(string stringToFormat)
{
    CultureInfo cultureInfo = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
    TextInfo textInfo = cultureInfo.TextInfo;

    // Check if we have a string to format
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(stringToFormat))
    {
        // Return an empty string
        return string.Empty;
    }

    // Format the string to Proper Case
    return textInfo.ToTitleCase(stringToFormat.ToLower());
}
```

Comment: Your solution was obviously too long - his machine can't copy paste more than 3 lines at a time ;)

Comment: @Neurofluxation: What's with the snooty remark? Internet anonymity brings the douches out of the woodwork it seems.

Comment: * **smiles** * ah well, no sense of humour on SO - I forgot

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
        string inputString = "this is a test";

        string outputString = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(inputString);
```

Comment: This is the correct modern answer.