# How to capitalize the first letter in each word in string in c#

Tags: c#, string, asp.net-mvc-5, char

I have tried researching *'Questions that may already have your answer'* but none of them really aided in this since most of them deal with different programming languages..

So in regards to C#, specifically ASP.NET MVC, in my *Create* action I have the code to capitalize the very first character of the first word in the string, but if the user enters in 2 words, the first character of the 2nd word stays lowercase.

Here is what I have so far in my **Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,text,subcategory")] Activities codeAC)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        char firstLetter = codeAC.text[0];

        if (char.IsLower(firstLetter))
        {
            codeAC.text = codeAC.text.First().ToString().ToUpper() + String.Join("", codeAC.text.Skip(1));
        }
```

How do I modify this so that if the user enters in *'test test2'* the result being saved into the database would be *'Test Test2'*, not *'Test test2'*?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I've marked your answer as a duplicate of [How can I capitalize each first letter of a word in a sentence?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067928/how-can-i-capitalize-each-first-letter-of-a-word-in-a-sentence?rq=1) since the answers there perfectly apply to your question and it's specific to C#. If you feel the answers don't work, please explain why.

Comment: @p.s.w.g thank you for that, I will delete this.. I didn't even find that question. thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This will help you :

```
 string inString = "test test2 test test2 test test2";
 TextInfo cultInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).TextInfo;
 string output = cultInfo.ToTitleCase(inString);
 // Test Test2 Test Test2 Test Test2
```

where `CultureInfo` belongs to `System.Globalization`.

Note `cultInfo.ToTitleCase("some value");`  will work only for a sentence having all small letters, consider an example: `input`: `"this will be an EXAMPLE"` then the above code will convert it into `"This Will Be An EXAMPLE"`. that means `EXAMPLE` remains in the capital. So what we need to do is, make the entire string into the lower case before performing this operation. so the input will be like the following:

```
 string inString = "test test2 test test2 test test2";
```